# PIC18F46J50 EEPROM read/write

Tags: c, embedded, pic18, eeprom, usart

The project i am working is as below:

I got ADuC7061's USART is connected with PIC18F46j50 EUSART. the aduc7061 continously transmits an information and the pic18f receives that information through its eusart0.

Now the question is that I have to store that information on pic18's eeprom and then display that information after some manipulation onto 128x64 graphics display.

Comment: So, what is your question? Really?

Comment: How to write on eeprom the value pic18f receives from aduc7061 ?

Comment: The [PIC18F46J50](http://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1004&mid=10&lang=en&pageId=74) does not have EEPROM memory.

Comment: Could I use Flash memory ?

Comment: Yes, if your requirements allow it (e.g. less maximum write cycles than eeprom, only page-wise erasure etc.). See http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01095c.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PIC18F46J50](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39931d.pdf) does not have integrated EEPROM memory. You have two alternatives:

- Use a PIC which contains EEPROM memory. See http://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1004&mid=10&lang=en&pageId=74 for a product selection table.
- Use the program flash memory. This has some drawbacks like less number of maximum write cycles compared to EEPROM and only bank-wise erasure, but might be sufficient depending on your requirements. See also [Emulating Data EEPROM for PIC18 and PIC24 Microcontrollers](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01095c.pdf)

Comment: Is it possible to display the received value through EUSART on display without being storing on flash memory ?

Comment: Sure - you can store the data in RAM and process it from there

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do this? I am new to PIC mic. Cheers

Comment: I fear this is out-of-scope on StackOverflow :) You should browse through the MicroChip web site for application notes, use google to find additional information and then get started. Once you have some code and are stuck, come back to SO and post your concrete question. Generally, it should not be that difficult: Read the data from the USART, store it in RAM, use some conversions to convert the data into a readable ASCII string and send it to your display. I would start with the display, to be able to also use it for debug output.